# "PHP" is showing up in Browser + OS list in Google Analytics report

Tags: google-analytics, php, server-side-scripting, browser-detecting

`PHP` is listed as a browser in Google Analytics. 50 sessions have been created.

[image: Screenshot of Google Analytics showing PHP as browser]

Obviously Analytics data is collected via Javascript executed in the visitor's browser so what is PHP (a server-side language) doing in this list?!

My own server is PHP and there is a server-side script that records certain Events by pushing data into GA. I checked the Events report and sure enough, there was the exact same number 50, as the number of `Unique Events`.

[image: Screenshot of Google Analytics showing 50 events]

So we can safely assume that these stats are actually about hits on the GA API. But why are my own server-side requests to Analytics being bundled in with data which should be about the users? I look at the Browser + OS report to learn about my site's Users, surely mixing in information about my server-side requests to the API is misleading?! PHP is not one of my users browsers, it is my own server pushing user data into my Analytics account.

Is there a some parameters I can add to the API requests?  Should I be capturing the User Agent string myself and passing that to the GA API? If so, do I then capture the IP Address, language et cetera, the never ending list of things GA records. Can I just tell GA not to include the information about which server is hitting the API but instead, just the information given to the API?

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue where "WordPress" is appearing as the Browser. I can confirm that this has to do with server-side analytics events. I'm currently troubleshooting a few ideas including adding more parameters (based on Google's [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters)), or sending a non-interaction parameter (as 'ni' => 1 in my array).

Answer (score 2):

Sending a non-interaction parameter with the Event hit type seems to keep the sessions at 0. The only issue I see now is that the "New Users" column still has data in it. This does not affect the graph or the total number of hits/sessions/pageviews, but I wanted to note it.

The syntax for a non-interaction is `'ni'` (boolean) where 1 is non-interaction, and 0 is interaction. I've just added this into all of my server-side event tracking with a default of true. This seems to have fixed most of the problem.

[Here it is on the documentation page.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#ni)

Hope this helps. It seems like not a lot of people are having this issue, so it's tough to find any clues/answers.

Answer (score 1):

Very likely an automated script hitting your site and trigger analytics to fire. PHP can be a valid user agent, at least according to http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

I would drill down in to the PHP analytics and then view the location of those visitors, time on site, page views and more to try and determine if it's a script or person.

Comment: Not really added anything that wasn't in the question. It is fair to assume this strange data is about my script.  The question is **WHY** GA is recording a script which is not a user's browser executing Javascript but my own server trying to give a specific set of data to GA. The API is recording the messenger not just the message.